# Copy Multiple files from HDFS to local: Multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, hadoop, hdfs

In my Java application, I need to copy multiple files from HDFS to Local File System.

Which of the below two approaches will be faster ?
1. Sequentially copy files one-by-one
2. Run parallel threads to copy each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one physical disk as part of your local file system than a sequential approach would be best, as a parallel approach would cause the disk (in the case of a hard drive) to spin back and forth unnecessarily (depending on how much the OS can help you or not and the nature of the writes), and also because you would only have one physical resource to work with at a time, so one thread would be good enough.

If this local file system has multiple physical disks, then the possibility of running parallel threads for more performance could be ideal (like Thread A writes all files that are going to drive C, while thread B writes all files that are going to drive D).

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)
I agree with your answer if we are copying files from Local FS to Local FS.
But, in the case of copy from HDFS to Local FS, I think that the overall Network IO time will be reduced through a parallel copy. Hence, overall Disk I/O might become slow, but network I/O would be faster.
So, does it still makes sense to sequentially copy files from HDFS to Local FS ?

Comment: If the network I/O can be reduced through parallel means that perhaps just make that parallel and buffer the data needing to be written by the one file system writing thread. I don't have too much knowledge on what's the best for network I/O though.